# How to solve SMTNotSupported extension by the server Error?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, email-confirmation, python-django-storages

Actually i am creating a registration form using django and when user will submit it he will get successful registration mail but it will give me error SMTPNotSupported extension server.
my settings.py file

- EMAIL_HOST = 'smpt.gmail.com'
  EMAIL_PORT = 587
  EMAIL_HOST_USER = myusername
  EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = my password
  EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend

---

I am sharing my error photo with you all.

Comment: Its “smtp” not “smpt”. You have a spelling mistake in your email host setting...

Comment: No i haven't done spelling mistake in my code that is now in question but not in my code